How to change menu actionitem background Color?
Ok I feel like an idiot,
my menu action item has this dark color that does not even exist in my theme,

But my menu_item xml is setting it to be a tan color,
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/tanlight"
    tools:context="com.example.encryptednotes.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:background="@color/tanlight"
        android:itemBackground="@color/tanlight"
        android:panelFullBackground="@color/tanlight"
        android:theme="@style/CustomMenuItemStyle"
        />
</menu>

I've made so many changes I had to delete my feature branch and start over.  How do I change the background color?

See doc Material Components - Menu: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md,  action flow menu's background is control by attribute "?attr/actionOverflowMenuStyle".

This could be due to the fact that menu's often inherit their styling from App's theme. You have to ensure that your theme applies correct color scheme to popup menu's. Better if you share the AndroidManifest.xml code to see what theme you are using or create a custom theme and define colors for PopUpMenu style.
